# How to find free ports after SocketUtils has been deprecated in spring boot 3?

Tags: java, spring, sockets, spring-boot-3

`org.springframwork.util.SocketUtils` has been deprecated in spring boot 3. Please provide a code snippet on how to find free ports within a specified range.

I am interested in alternate solutions for `SocketUtils.findAvailableTcpPorts(requestedNumberOfPorts, minimumPortValue, maximumPortValue)` which would return any requested no. of ports from a specified range and `SocketUtils.findAvailableTcpPort(minimumPortValue, maximumPortValue)`

Comment: What is the usecase for this? There is still suppor tin the test packages but that is intended for test support not production support.

Comment: I am working on migration from spring boot 2 to 3. The application finds free ports using SocketUtils, which are used to establish web socket connection and other use cases.

Comment: That doesn't really answer my question but please add it to your question as well instead of just a comment. Is this during regular usage or during testing was more of the question.

Comment: So, your code has a bug. But instead of fixing the bug, you want to keep it. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another alternative is to use Java's **ServerSocket** class to find available TCP ports.
Here's a code snippet how you can do it, HTH.

```
import java.net.ServerSocket;

private static boolean isPortAvailable(int port) {
    try (ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port)) {
        return true;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // Port is not available
        return false;
    }
```